# Apply function across all columns using the column name - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

### Basically:

Is there a way to apply a function that uses the column name of a dataframe in Pandas?
Like this:

```
df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(labels_dict[column_name][x]), axis=1)
```

Where column name is the column that the `apply` is 'processing'.

---

### Details:

I'd like to create a label for each row of a dataframe, based on a dictionary.

Let's take the dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Application': ['Compressors', 'Fans', 'Fans', 'Material Handling'],
                'HP': ['0.25', '0.25', '3.0', '15.0'],
                'Sector': ['Commercial', 'Industrial', 'Commercial', 'Residential']},
                index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

After I apply the label:

```
In [139]: df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)

In [140]: df
Out[140]:
         Application    HP       Sector                               label
0        Compressors  0.25   Commercial         Compressors_0.25_Commercial
1               Fans  0.25   Industrial                Fans_0.25_Industrial
2               Fans   3.0   Commercial                 Fans_3.0_Commercial
3  Material Handling  15.0  Residential  Material Handling_15.0_Residential
```

But the label is too long, especially when I consider the full dataframe, which contains a lot more columns. What I want is to use a dictionary to shorten the fields that come from the columns (I pasted the code for the dictionary at the end of the question).

I can do that for one field:

```
In [145]: df['application_label'] = df['Application'].apply(
                                               lambda x: labels_dict['Application'][x])

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
         Application    HP       Sector application_label
0        Compressors  0.25   Commercial               cmp
1               Fans  0.25   Industrial               fan
2               Fans   3.0   Commercial               fan
3  Material Handling  15.0  Residential               mat
```

But I want to do it for all the fields, like I did in snippet #2. So I'd like to do something like:

```
df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(labels_dict[column_name][x]), axis=1)
```

Where column name is the column of `df` to which the function is being applied. Is there a way to access that information?

Thank you for your help!

---

I defined the dictionary as:

```
In [141]: labels_dict
Out[141]:
{u'Application': {u'Compressors': u'cmp',
  u'Fans': u'fan',
  u'Material Handling': u'mat',
  u'Other/General': u'oth',
  u'Pumps': u'pum'},
 u'ECG': {u'Polyphase': u'pol',
  u'Single-Phase (High LRT)': u'sph',
  u'Single-Phase (Low LRT)': u'spl',
  u'Single-Phase (Med LRT)': u'spm'},
 u'Efficiency Level': {u'EL0': u'el0',
  u'EL1': u'el1',
  u'EL2': u'el2',
  u'EL3': u'el3',
  u'EL4': u'el4'},
 u'HP': {0.25: 1.0,
  0.33: 2.0,
  0.5: 3.0,
  0.75: 4.0,
  1.0: 5.0,
  1.5: 6.0,
  2.0: 7.0,
  3.0: 8.0,
  10.0: 9.0,
  15.0: 10.0},
 u'Sector': {u'Commercial': u'com',
  u'Industrial': u'ind',
  u'Residential': u'res'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked out one way to do it, but it seems clunky. I'm hoping there's something more elegant out there.

```
df['label'] = pd.DataFrame([df[column_name].apply(lambda x: labels_dict[column_name][x])
    for column_name in df.columns]).apply('_'.join)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a bit more elegant

```
df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join([str(labels_dict[col][v]) for col, v in zip(df.columns, x)]), axis=1)
```